# problem with importing pyinputplus module

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem with importing module pyinputplus to my project.
I type 'pip install pyinputplus' in cmd (iam using windows), all was fine, cmd showed that installation was succes.
But when i try: import pyinputplus in my project in PyCharm i have an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinputplus'

Some weeks ago i installed packed named selenium, and everything was fine. All works with no problem. I do the same with pyinputplus and its wrong...

Moreover, i tried to use pyinputplus in cmd and all was also fine. Where is a problem?

Comment: you have to check which python environment pycharm is using and wheter `pyinputplus` is installed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pycharm creates virtual environments for each project, so installing it system-wide (as you just did) doesn't make it available to your pycharm project.

## Easier Solution

The easy solution is to go to preferences, click "python interpreter" (you may need to expand "project"), then click the plus icon at the bottom of the package list, and search for `pyinputplus` and click install. It is now installed, but won't work for any other project.

## Long-term Solution

Keeping packages seperate has it's advantages, like allowing you to have many different versions of packages, and avoid conflicts, but you may prefer for everything to use the same interpreter. If so, go to the same "python interpreter" page in preferences, and change the interpreter in the dropdown to the other available one. If there are more than 2, you may need to use trial and error.

Have a look at the documentation here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#interpreter-settings

Comment: If this works, you might want to mark it as "accepted" (the tick), so that people later on can see that this question is answered.